If $\delta(G) \ge n$ does this imply existence of a $K_{n+1}$ minor?
That is, if each vertex in $G$ has degree at least $n$, is this condition sufficient to force a $K_{n+1}$ minor, or are there any obvious counter-examples for any particular values of $n$?

You have to impose also an upper bound on the number of nodes, otherwise this is false for every $n$

No, this is not true. Take a planar graph with $\delta(G) \geq 4$ (obviously such graphs exist). But a planar graph cannot have $K_5$ as a minor.
As an added fact, the average degree needed to force $K_t$ as a minor is roughly $\sim t(\log t)^{1/2}$ as $t \to \infty$, so it is expected that this statement is false. See Section 3 of this survey.

Take $n$ even. Notice that you can always find a $n$-regular graph with $n+k$  nodes ($k\ge 2$) that is connected and thus does not contain any $K_{n+1}$. For example, enumerate the nodes from $1$ to $n+k$ and connect any node to the previous $n/2$ and the following $n/2$ cyclically.
If $n$ is odd, start from the same construction connecting each node  to the previous $(n-1)/2$ and the following $(n-1)/2$ cyclically, and then add the edges $1 \to (n+3)/2$, $2 \to (n+5)/2$, ..., $(n-1)/2+k \to n+k$. The minimum degree is always $n$. Notice that nodes at distance strictly greater than $(n+1)/2$ are never connected. As a consequence, all nodes in a $K_{n+1}$ must be at distance at most $(n+1)/2$ from each other, that is impossible for $n>1$ since $(n+1)/2<n$.
So the statement is true only for $n=1$ or if the number of nodes of the graph is exactly $n+1$.
